# AWS Ec2 Access which is private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

This is more of an architectural question rather than coding issue.
Please pardon me if I am in wrong place
I have an Ec2 instance running in private VPC where we in future are
going to deploy PII data and by no mean we can have internet access to it.
However We need to install ETL tool in docker(Airflow, docker, nifi, python etc)
and ofcourse need to ssh into from my local company vpc.

There is two approach as far as I think is

```
    1. To create an another EC2 in public subnet and install all our tool there 
       and call the VPC EC2 from this one. 
       So that I can move the PII data to S3 through private Endpoint.
    
    Cons: Does not it still raise the security concern as the EC2(ETL) is still
    in internet where from one can access the PII data in second ec2.
```

Another Option

```
2. To create the Ec2 in public and install all tools and then 
    finally change it into private VPC.
    Cons: in case if tool crash or there is any change needed then will have to 
    move it back to public which again does not look proper way of handling it.
```

I tried to search internet to get any tutorial or training about it.
But cannot find it.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use internet at all if you don't want. I assume that by **no internet access** you mean that this is two ways - no access from the internet to the instance, nor the instance can connect internet at all (i.e. no NAT or any other proxy).

There are a **couple of ways** of doing this. One way is as follows:

1. Prepare **custom AMI** with per-installed all packages and software that you require.
2. Create **private VPC** without any public subnets.
3. Add **VPC interface endpoints** to the VPC for S3, AWS System Manager, ECR (to store your private docker images) and other AWS services you may require, e.g. KMS.
4. **Launch** your instance from the custom AMI in the private VPC.
5. Use **SSM Session Manager** to "ssh" to the instance without any internet access.

Comment: @danD No problem. You will need to setup instance role for the SSM Session Manager and add necessary vpc interface endpoints. Not sure you know how to do it, or should add some links for that?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. I find some tutorial and created and started the SSM to access which seems I can do now.. However since I am using SSM role (AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore) now.. I am wondering how i will use bucket policy IAM to access S3 bucket where i used to allow s3 bucket access.. As i notice one ec2 only allow one IAM role.. please give your suggestion..

Comment: @danD You would add instance role's ARN as principle to your bucket policy.

Comment: One last question (hopefully).. Since i am going to install an airflow which time by time will need to have updated pipeline .. How we do that is to add/update python code in dag folder of airflow docker application.. Will I be able to add the script in EC2 through SSM.. Not to mention I will mount an EBS as well into the EC2. EBS will be using KMS encryption.. And thanks a lot for all the suggestion you give

Comment: @danD I'm not to familiar with airflow. But you could store code in S3 first, and then copy to the instance using aws cli after you connect to it using SSM. You could also automate all this through CodeDeploy or SSM Run Command.  EBS encryption is transparent - AWS take cares of it. You shouldn't need to do anything for it to work in VPC.

Comment: boom.. yes I can use S3 for deploying any code to Ec2.. Thanks a lot for all this precious suggestion Now I will get my hand dirty and try to bring all this into Life.. Thanks a lot for all your suggestion..

Comment: Another question.. I install all application(web) in public ec2 check the website and all pipeline. etc.. and created AMI from it.. Now I will create private EC2 via private VPC but how will I access the Web ui as inbound and outbound port will be closed, I believe.

Comment: @danD Not sure what do you mean? The instance must be, as you wrote, fully separated from internet. So you can only access it from within the VPC, e.g. using VPN or proxy through some bastion instance in a public subnet.

Answer (score 0):

I think both approaches are inherently sub-optimal

If all you're trying to do is avoid exposing your compute instances to the internet, and your setup is docker based, simply setup your own docker repository, either using ECS or Sonatype Nexus (on another server), upload your docker images there and have that node use that ECS/Nexus as its docker registry.

That way, your enjoying free access to all resources exposed as docker images while maintaining security compliance.

Comment: Thanks this look feasible, I am going to try that just now.. However could you please suggest how to ssh into this Ec2. As for testing purpose even in security of the Ec2 I put inound to port 22 open.. but still when i try to ssh it shows timeout error.

Comment: If you didn't assign a public IP address, or put that instance on private subnet not connected to the internet (it has no Internet Gateway in the VPC), you won't be able to connect it externally without some sort of intermediary machine (bastion host)